# A Blank Screen Is Displayed while Adding Firebase.initizeApp in My Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart

After running my project, a white screen appeared without any errors. added Firebase.initializeApp() to main.dart and When I don't insert Firebase.initializeApp()then it display Firebase No App

```
> Future<void> main() async {  
> WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();   await
> Firebase.initializeApp();   SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
>       [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);   initNotifications();   runApp(MyApp()); }
> 
> class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {   static const appName = 'Marc
> Jr Foundation';
> 
> //https://upcdatabase.org/   @override   Widget build(BuildContext
> context) {
>     return MultiProvider(
>       child: Provider<AuthBase>(
>         create: (context) => Auth(),
>         child: MaterialApp(
>           debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
>           theme: ThemeData(
>             backgroundColor: Color(0xffF4F3F2),
>             appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
>               // color: Color(0xff303F9F),
>               // color: Color(0xffA3CE44),
>               color: Color(0xffDE3897),
>               //color: Colors.cyan[500],
>               elevation: 10.0,
>             ),
>             iconTheme: IconThemeData(
>               color: Colors.white,
>               size: 20.0,
>             ),
>             textTheme: TextTheme(
>               button: TextStyle(
>                 fontSize: 13.0,
>                 color: Colors.white,
>               ),
>             ),
>           ),
```

I tried Flutter Clean
Flutter Sdk uninstall and install
flutter upgrade
flutter pub get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure these lines of code are right :

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check have you added this File

google-services.json

Comment: Yes I have my google-service.json file in android folder

Answer (score 0):

I was developing a Flutter *web* app -- web ONLY. `Firebase.initializeApp` in my `main()` was no problem for `flutter run`, but when built and deployed I got a blank screen and an unclear Console error.

**I had platform support for everything but only needed web. <-- *I think this was the problem.***

When I ran `flutterfire configure` I chose only the web platform.

After deleting all the unwanted platform folders from my project's top level (android, ios, macos, linux, windows), re-running `flutter pub get` && `flutterfire configure` just in case, things worked.